# Javascript to flash communication

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I am trying to call a Actionscript function from javascript but I am having problems in Internet Explorer.
I am using Swiff.remote in mootools 1.2.1 to call the actionscript function ie:

```
Swiff.remote(playSwf.toElement(), 'sendResult', result, plays, name);
```

This all works fine in FireFox, Safari and Opera but I'm getting an "unspecified" error in Internet Explorer 6 and 7.
I have tried using the bog standard:

```
window['flash'].sendResult(result, plays, name);
```

To no avail.

Thanks for any help.
Mark

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the Swiff plugin, but you don't need a plugin to call flash functions from Javascript. It's even easier to do it natively.

From AS:

```
//1. calling javascript function from Flash.
ExternalInterface.call("sendData",tempStr);
// argument 1: javascript function, argument 2: data/variables to pass out.
//2. calling javascript function from Flash with recursion.
var returnValue:String = ExternalInterface.call("sendReturn",tempStr).toString();
//3. setting up a callback function for javascript
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callFlash",flashResponse);
// argument 1: function name called by javascript, argument 2: function on the Flash side.
// AS2 version looks like this : ExternalInterface.addCallback("callFlash",null,flashResponse);
```

From JS:

```
//1. javascript function as called from Flash.
function sendData(val){
    alert(val);
    document.flashForm.flashOutput.value = val;
}

//2. javascript function with recursion.
function sendReturn(val){
    var tempData = "Hello from JS";
    return tempData + ' :return';
}

//3. calling Flash function with javascript.
function sendToFlash(val){
    window['flash'].callFlash(val);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried with:

window['flash'].sendResult(result, plays, name);

How are you referencing your flash object? window['flashname/flashid']

Comment: Ah, of course. There must be a different way of grabbing that in IE. Maybe something like window.document.name... not sure on that.

Comment: Try window.document.getElementsByName('flashname').

Comment: It's not necessary to reference the flash with the `window` object, you can just reference by ID: http://work.arounds.org/calling-flash-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Ah, here is the answer to you problem.

```
<form>
    <input type="button" onclick="callExternalInterface(id)" value="Call ExternalInterface" />
</form>
<script>
function callExternalInterface(id) {
    thisMovie("externalInterfaceExample").callAS(id);
}

function thisMovie(movieName) {
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) {
        return window[movieName]
    }
    else {
        return document[movieName]
    }
}
</script>
```

SO if the client is Internet Explorer, you should be fetching the movie from the document object. :-)

Comment: What errors are you getting?  This solutions seems sound, I wonder if there is some other factors causing your issues.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post this answer, as this *may* be what's causing problems for others, obviously this is not causing your problem. Still looking into a solution for your issue.

From the MooTools Docs: http://mootools.net/docs/Utilities/Swiff
Note:

The SWF file must be compiled with the ExternalInterface component. See the Adobe documentation on External Interface for more information.

Action Script 2.0

```
import flash.external.*;
```

Action Script 3.0

```
package com
{
   import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
   public class Main 
   {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you out, looks like a similar problem but using the swfobject.

http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/forum/discussion/1064/swfobject-21-problems-with-externalinterface-in-ie/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it directly:

```
playSwf.remote('sendResult', result, plays, name)
```

Of course `sendResult` has to be registered with `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` in the AS code *and* the flash file has to fully loaded (otherwise all calls fail).

An example can be found in this [github repository (fancyupload)](http://github.com/digitarald/digitarald-fancyupload/tree/master/source): The as3proj contains the AS source, the JS remote calls are in *Swiff.Uploader.js*.

Answer (score 0):

If your code works in all browsers except Internet Explorer, it's a good bet that it's because the Flash Player for IE is an ActiveX plugin.  I read somewhere that ActiveX communicates in .NET format and Flash's external API communicates in XML.

I'm also trying to learn Javascript-Flash communication on Internet Explorer, so I'll keep you folks posted on what I learn.