# How to access an html element in flash?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript, dhtml

I have an html page with a flash movie embded in it, that flash movie contains a button. I want to pass the id of an element on the containing html page to the flash movie so that when the button is clicked, I get the text of that element in flash (i.e. innerHTML).

So, my question is basically two questions:

- How to pass something from HTML/Javascript to flash?
- How to access an element on the containing html page from flash? (What ActionScript code is needed to do that?)

Many thanks ...

Edit:

I found the answer to the first question (use Flash Vars), hope someone can help me with the other one.

Answer (score 2):

[See this StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312880/actionscript3-to-javascript-communication-best-practices) about the use of the [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/2/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class in ActionScript.