# AS3 window class which can hold components

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, class, window

I need to create a "popup window" in AS3, which can contain things like textboxes and datagrids and stuff like that.

I have searched thoroughly, and have been unable to find such a component or class. Why did they remove the AS2 window in as3? That would have been perfect for this.

The closest thing I could find was http://fatal-exception.co.uk/blog/?p=69 which cannot support textboxes or datagrids.

Thanks for your help, I need this very badly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to build a window class myself quite easily. It has some decent functionality.

I used `startDrag(false)` and `stopDrag();` to program the dragging functionality, and `this.parent.removeChild(this);` to get rid of the window.

Comment: That doesn't answer your own question, so should not be considered an answer.

Comment: It includes the basic functionality needed to make a "window". Implementation is up to whoever is using the code. I'm afraid you misinterpreted my question. The main question is not why the component was removed in as3, rather how can I create something which in effect mimics its capabilities. I feel your downvote was unnecessary, "drowntoge" provided a similar answer yet you did not downvote them. Please explain your logic.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want to do.

If you want to create a display object at the top of your application, then create a new layer directly on stage. That can have anything you like in it, and you can make it draggable or whatever you wish.

If you want to create a Flash window that floats above the browser, then you can't. Or rather, you can, but you need to create a new window using JavaScript (called from ExternalInterface, see [this StackO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299729/javascript-to-flash-communication)), load in a new SWF, and then link the two SWFs using LocalConnection. This is really unsatisfactory though, because LocalConnection is broken (in a whole host of ways).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a class that extends MovieClip, include a TextField at the top as the title, an X button to close it, event handlers in order to handle dragging etc.
You can then instantiate the class and add the items to be shown as children.

Comment: Pretty much what I eventually did